# Get percentage of owned parts needed to complete a set, comparing two tables with integer values

Tags: mysql, integer, compare

I'll start with the pic:

[image: tables and desired output]

I see now that I forgot to add "owned" in the second column in the Desired output table, but hopefully you should see what I am trying to accomplish here.

Essentially I want to join the two example tables above in order to create an output like the third. I could solve it using Count() / Count() * 100 on a left join had there been 1 item per row, but how do I get each products completeness using the integers provided?

I've seen systems that can do this, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

PS: Real tables will have about 20k products with anything from 5 to 4000 parts each.

Comment: am I even on the right track with something like:

    `SELECT A.Product,  

[something magical, that may or may not include   Count(AllTheProductsParts) / Count(OwnedParts) * 100]  

AS Completeness  
LEFT JOIN A ON A.PartID = B.PartID  
    GROUP BY Product ORDER BY Completeness DESC`

Comment: 890011 through 890016 are all supposed to be 890010, right?

Comment: yes, that's right - sorry, i missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS required; 

 CREATE TABLE required 
 (product INT NOT NULL
 ,partID INT NOT NULL
 ,Quantity   INT NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY (product,partID)
 );

 INSERT INTO required VALUES
 (41520   ,4107736 ,1),
 (41520   ,4142989 ,4),
 (41520   ,6047426 ,2),
 (41520   , 302328 ,6),
 (41520   ,6046381 ,1),
 (1253    ,6056225 ,2),
 (1253    ,3005749 ,2),
 (1253    ,4114011 ,2),
 (890010  ,4569733 ,2),
 (890010  ,6048855 ,2),
 (890010  ,6006739 ,2),
 (890010  ,6073026 ,2),
 (890010  ,6043639 ,2),
 (890010  ,6039479 ,2),
 (890010  ,4504382 ,3);

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS owned;

 CREATE TABLE owned 
 (partID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
 ,Quantity INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO owned VALUES
 (4142989 , 2),
 (6047426 , 2),
 (302328  , 2),
 (6039944 , 2),
 (4244573 , 2),
 (6046381 , 3),
 (6056225 , 2),
 (3005749 , 1),
 (4114011 , 2),
 (4264419 , 2),
 (6036850 , 2),
 (6030276 , 1),
 (6023954 , 2),
 (4164037 , 1),
 (4537937 ,14),
 (4567882 , 1),
 (4569733 , 2),
 (6048855 , 2),
 (6006739 , 2),
 (6073026 , 2),
 (6043639 , 2),
 (6039479 , 2),
 (4504382 , 3),
 (6069000 , 2),
 (374726  , 1),
 (4517925 , 2),
 (4598528 , 2),
 (6020193 , 2),
 (4107761 , 1);

 SELECT r.product
      , ROUND(LEAST(SUM(r.quantity),SUM(o.quantity)/SUM(r.quantity)) * 100,2) pct_owned 
   FROM required r 
   LEFT 
   JOIN owned o 
     ON o.partid = r.partid 
  GROUP 
     BY product;

 +---------+-----------+
 | product | pct_owned |
 +---------+-----------+
 |    1253 |     83.33 |
 |   41520 |     64.29 |
 |  890010 |    100.00 |
 +---------+-----------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74be1/2

Note that this doesn't take into account the fact that not all products could be assembled simultaneoulsy

Comment: you sir, are a god.

However, there is one fundamental flaw - if you had 1000 of a certain part then pct_owned would be way above 100% for that product - even though it could be missing the other parts of the set.

Ideally we don't want to count the owned parts that exceed the required part - can that be done?

Comment: In my omniscience, I'm pretty sure that I took that into account !!!... Ah, maybe you need to swap the leasts and the sums around

Comment: Try SUM(LEAST(r.quantity,o.quantity))/SUM(r.quantity))

Comment: I shall build thee an altar infront of which i shall worship thee every day - it works!

Comment: Whatever rocks your boat ;-)